# Plugins: Is there any events and/or calendar plugin in the making?

Tags: plugins

I'm in desperate need of a plugin that lets:

- Users create calendar events or (even better) lets you import those from Outlook or GCal.
- Visitors participate in an event and (after submitting a form) get a calendar request through e-mail

Does anyone know of any plugin(s) in the making, or should I start building my own?

Comment: I feel your pain T_T [this](https://github.com/tippingmedia/craft.events) looks promising. I'll add an answer once i've actually vetted it.

Comment: If you're still looking, I have a Calendars plugin in Private Beta. No importing function just yet, but it's on the roadmap. http://michaelrog.com/craftcalendars/

Answer (score 5):

Until the Craft plugin store becomes an "official things", the best, most curated list of plugins available for Craft is over on [Straight Up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins)

The closest thing I can find on there to what you're looking for is the "[Recurring Dates](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/recurring-dates)" plugin.

Comment: Brad, I'm well aware of that nice list, couldn't find what I was looking for on it though. Was hoping that you Crafty guys, in your infinite wisdom, would be my hero-of-the-day with one of the following answers: 

- That plugin is in the making, ask X.
- You can do this with Craft out of the box, just use Y.

Guess I'll have to make it myself, then.

Comment: @PaulVerheul Have heard rumors and whispers of various people working on something along these lines, but for the life of me, can't recall any of them at the moment.

Comment: I think the time has come for rumorsandwhispers.buildwithcraft.com ...

Answer (score 5):

**I'm happy to report that *[Craft Calendars](https://topshelfcraft.com/calendars)* is officially released.**

The *Calendars* plugin enables you to set up multiple calendars, repeating/recurring events, multi-language content, monthly calendar views, etc.

iCal/Google import/export is on the roadmap, coming in version *1.1*/*1.2*.

More info: **https://topshelfcraft.com/calendars**

As of right now, *Craft Calendars* is the only production-ready/supported plugin for event management that I'm aware of, but others are in the works, at varying stages of development, including:

- [Venti](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/venti), by Tipping Media
- [craft-recurring-events](https://github.com/nxnw/craft-recurring-dates), by Dan Fockler
- [Events](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events), an example plugin by Pixel & Tonic

Comment: Very classy move, giving a shout out to the competition... But I'll still **completely vouch for Craft Calendars**. We used the beta on a couple of sites, and it's a very solid product!

Answer (score 5):

We recently launched Venti 2 – a powerful event calendar management plugin built exclusively for Craft CMS! Check it out at https://venticalendar.io

Answer (score 4):

I know of about five people/agencies working on calendar/event plugins but almost all off them are in early stages. There is one that I've gotten a sneak peak at that may be ready sooner than later. I've done very light consulting on said plugin but the person to ask about it if you're curios is my buddy  [@adamrandlett](http://twitter.com/adamrandlett) since he's the main developer on that project.

A general commerce platform and a solid calendar are two missing pieces in the plugin ecosystem right now mainly because these two are hard to do well.

Anyway, just wanted to say there is hope but no quick answer yet!

Comment: Anything around yet? I need something like this as well and was really hoping i could avoid building it myself.

Comment: http://michaelrog.com/craftcalendars/