# Kind of virtual entries possible?

Tags: entries, relations, entry, calendar

we are currently working on a website with an event calendar on it. The events should be filterable by categories and dates of course. Some of these events are repeated on another date. Now we are looking for a strategy to add the same event on another day without duplicating the entry and just modifying it's date. Is there a way to add an entry with it's own date but it inherits the contents and relations of another entry? These "virtual" entries should behave like "real" entries, so if the calendar is being filtered by the category "concerts" for example, all entries/virtual entries related to "concerts" should be listed. Any hint on that matter?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Possibly related? http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/plugins-is-there-any-events-and-or-calendar-plugin-in-the-making

Comment: Also: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15853/events-calendar-for-craft-which-one-should-i-use

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply! We'll look into Solspace Calendar which appears to be very powerful and should fulfil our requirements.